# Jenkins was stopped running because can not create cpuset directory

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I'm trying to run jenkins with my custom Dockerfile using docker-compose. But the container doesn't go on running then I get some errors about creating a directory. I don't understand that, user is root in container already and how it possible to get this error?

Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml and container logs are

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins
 
USER root

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -qqy apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common

RUN curl -fsSL download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -

RUN add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -qqy docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "service docker start && /sbin/tini -- /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  s_jenkins:
    container_name: c_jenkins
    build: .
    image: recep/jenkins
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    volumes:
      - /home/recep/Desktop/docker_learn/jenkins/data:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Logs:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘cpuset’: Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I change tini path, the problem is gone. Here is correct entrypoint

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "service docker start && /usr/bin/tini -- /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"]
```